# Java Mapping Mixed Types

Tags: java, hashmap

I am looking for a way to create a HashMap that maps to mixed types.

For example, the following would work in Python (note that a Python `dict` is similar to a Java `HashMap`):

```
d = dict()
d["str"] = "This is a string"
d["flt"] = 1.23
d["int"] = 5
```

and when accessing `d[x]`, the appropriate type would be returned (string, float, int in this example).

In Java, I could go with a `HashMap<String, Object>`, but I don't really have a way to immediately tell what type each Object is.

So instead, I'm currently trying to do is create a `MixedType` class that holds an object, but also its original type information, so that I can downcast it later.  For example:

```
public class MixedMap
    public static class MixedType
    {
        public Class<?> cls;
        public Object val;

        public MixedType(Class<?> c, Object v)
        {
            this.cls = c;
            this.val = v;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String args[])
    {   
        MixedType m1 = new MixedType(String.class, "This is a String");
        System.out.println((m1.cls)m1.val);
    }
}
```

Note that this is what I'm *trying* to do :-)
as it's currently not compiling complaining that `m1 cannot be resolved to a type`.

So my question is, how can I fix this?  Other ways to achieve the same goal would be welcomed, but please don't answer telling me that this limits the type checking ability of the compiler -- I know that and am OK with it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can I just ask: what will you do with the objects once retrieved?  I feel like typically there's a better way to design this to avoid having to cast at all.

Comment: Even if you have type information stored in your plain `objects`, how do you expect to know what to do after you cast them?

Comment: Sure, I'll be using the HashMap as a "configuration" type object, where the user will specify certain configuration settings which will be parsed and put into this map.  At certain points in the program I will check to see if a certain configuration option is set, if so use it and if not use the default.  The reason for the need for mixed types is that some configuration options will be strings, others floats, others ints, etc.

Comment: @jedwards, the only realistic way to do what you're proposing is just to go ahead and cast the values to the types you know they have -- so something like `(String) config.get(propertyThatIsAString);`

Comment: @Louis, at the point of use?  That's an interesting alternative.  I think that should work fine.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The proper thing to do is `m1.cls.cast(m1.val)`, but you almost certainly won't gain anything as compared to a plain  `Map<String, Object>`.  A simpler approach that would get you exactly as much type safety and exactly the same information -- which is to say, not much -- would just be to use the `getClass()` method on the `Object` values in your map.

None of this will accomplish your goal of being able to say `String value = map.get("str")` -- nothing short of an outright cast would do that.  You could do

```
Object value = map.get("str");
if (value instanceof String) {
  // do stringy things
}
```

or something along those lines.

If you know the types of the values at their use points at compile time, then by far the best solution is just to go ahead and do the casts at the usage points.  The "ideal" way to do configuration like this in general is not to use a `Map`, but to build a customized `Configuration` class that knows its fields and their types at compile time, but if you want to use a `Map`, then just doing the casts directly is probably your best bet.

Comment: Thank you for the numerous alternative solutions!

Answer (score 4):

I've implemented something similar to this before.  You can use generics to assist.  What you want is a `MixedKey`, that you can use as a key into a `MixedMap`.  Something along these lines:

```
public class MixedKey<T> {
    public final Class<T> cls;
    public final String key;

    public MixedKey(T cls, String key) {
        this.key = key;
        this.cls = cls;
    }

    // also implement equals and hashcode
}
```

.

```
public class MixedMap extends HashMap<MixedKey<?>,Object> {
    public <T> T putMixed(MixedKey<T> key, T value) {
        return key.cls.cast(put(key, value));
    }

    public <T> T getMixed(MixedKey<T> key) {
        return key.cls.cast(get(key));
    }
}
```

The nice thing about doing something like this is it will give you a compile-time error if you use the wrong type by mistake, something you don't get with direct casting:

```
MixedKey<Integer> keyForIntProperty
    = new MixedKey<Integer>(Integer.class, "keyForIntProperty");

// ...

String str = mixedMap.getMixed(keyForIntProperty); // compile-time error
```

vs.

```
String str = (String)map.get("keyForIntProperty"); // run-time error only
```